# How to free HRGN after CreatePolygonRgn?

Tags: delphi, winapi, memory-management

I wrote a very simple method below in full, it creates a polygon around all components on the `TForm`. As there is no `HRGN.Free` method, which the compiler of Delphi XE6 pointed out, **I am merely asking if I should `Free`, well, *anything* in there**, I never used `HRGN` type before and want to know for sure. Thank you.

PS: I am asking solely on behalf of freeing the memory properly, if even needed here, nothing else.

---

```delphi
procedure TFormZoom.SetVisibleFormRegion;

var
    VisibleRegionPoints: array[0..11] of TPoint;
    VisibleFormRegion: HRGN;

begin
    try
        // XY points around all components that we want to be visible on the FormZoom
        VisibleRegionPoints[0] := Point(0, 0);
        VisibleRegionPoints[1] := Point(ZoomBoxPanel.Left + ZoomBoxPanel.Width, 0);
        VisibleRegionPoints[2] := Point(ZoomBoxPanel.Left + ZoomBoxPanel.Width, ZoomBoxPanel.Height);
        VisibleRegionPoints[3] := Point(ZoomBoxPanel.Left, ZoomBoxPanel.Height);
        VisibleRegionPoints[4] := Point(ZoomBoxPanel.Left, 0);
        VisibleRegionPoints[5] := Point(ColorBoxPanel.Width, 0);
        VisibleRegionPoints[6] := Point(ColorBoxPanel.Width, InfoValuesPanel.Top + InfoValuesPanel.Height);
        VisibleRegionPoints[7] := Point(0, InfoValuesPanel.Top + InfoValuesPanel.Height);
        VisibleRegionPoints[8] := Point(0, InfoValuesPanel.Top);
        VisibleRegionPoints[9] := Point(InfoValuesPanel.Width, InfoValuesPanel.Top);
        VisibleRegionPoints[10] := Point(ColorBoxPanel.Width, ColorBoxPanel.Height);
        VisibleRegionPoints[11] := Point(0, ColorBoxPanel.Height);
        try
            // we create a polygon region from the above points
            VisibleFormRegion := CreatePolygonRgn(VisibleRegionPoints, Length(VisibleRegionPoints), ALTERNATE);
            // finally, we set the FormZoom window region to the created polygon
            SetWindowRgn(Self.Handle, VisibleFormRegion, True);
        finally
            VisibleFormRegion.Free;  // <-- There is no method called Free!
        end;
    except
        on E: Exception do
        begin
            // in case of error, we log the exception only
            FormMain.ErrorLog.Add('TFormZoom.SetVisibleFormRegion: ' + E.ClassName + ' - ' + E.Message);
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the documentation for [`CreatePolygonRgn()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createpolygonrgn), the returned handle must be freed with [`DeleteObject()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-deleteobject):

> When you no longer need the HRGN object, call the DeleteObject
> function to delete it.

**UPDATE**

As [Remy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau) pointed out: in your case, you're calling [`SetWindowRgn()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowrgn), which transfers the ownership of the region to the system. It means that you don't need to free it.

Comment: Except, DO NOT delete the region after passing it to `SetWindowRgn()`, per its [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowrgn): "*After a successful call to `SetWindowRgn`, the system owns the region specified by the region handle `hRgn`. The system does not make a copy of the region. Thus, you should not make any further function calls with this region handle. **In particular, do not delete this region handle**. The system deletes the region handle when it no longer needed.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau Good point. I've updated the answer.

Comment: "*It means that you don't need to free it*" - unless `SetWindowRgn()` fails, that is. Which is rare, but should be handled, just in case

Comment: @RemyLebeau I already made adjustments, which should check if those WinApi functions returned valid values, and act accordingly. Thank you again!